# I didn't provide a product key. Why is my Windows activated?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

**Update (Clarification)**

I ordered this PC from a very reliable store. I told them what parts I want (CPU, GPU, chassis, etc.), and they assembled it. Since I did not request an OS, they made sure that I'm aware that an OS is not included in the order. The PC arrived without any boot record, as expected. Even if the assemblers connected the machine to the internet, Windows was not installed, so no activation could happen upon assembly.

---

I bought a brand new desktop PC; it was assembled from all brand new parts.

I created a Windows 10 (20H2) installation media using the tool from Microsoft's website.

During the installation I clicked on "I don't have a product key" to skip activation.

Now, on Licensing it shows me that it is "activated with a digital license".

Executing `slmgr /xpr` results in "the machine is permanently activated".

It really bugs me. How is this possible?

Comment: The linked question is completely unrelated. Please unlink it.

Comment: Activation cannot happen in new (out of the manufacturer’s box) parts. Someone sold you used parts as new.

Comment: Changed the duplicate question and added a couple more. Essentially if you bought a "clean" box PC from the likes of Dell then it almost certainly has a licence baked in at the firmware level. If you bought a "generic parts" machine then chances are the people who built it powered it up and connected to the Internet and it activated a digital licence that way. In either case you apparently have a valid functional licence.

Comment: In either case for this not to be a duplicate you would need to explain the provenance and history of the machine. Did it come with Windows installed but you decided to wipe, or did it come as a machine without an operating system? Where did it come from? Any details are relevant. You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: It is possible that they had installed an OS, as in had a prebuilt system with OS ready and activated, but wiped it or simply replaced the disk prior to sending you the system. Digital entitlement is based on several hardware factors and just replacing the hard drive would not invalidate it. I guess you got lucky and have a free licence.

Comment: If you'd have built the machine from parts yourself then it would be incredibly odd for it to activate itself and something would be seriously wrong. But as there is a third party doing unknown stuff it boils down to "they screwed up and accidentally gave you a free licence". The duplicates answer the "why" your machine is licensed, as in because the hardware is entitled and correctly licenced,  the "how" it got a licence in the first place is down to the shop you bought it from and you'd need to contact them to find out.

Comment: I agree with Mokubai. The shop would have installed something in order to verify the parts worked and it was likely Windows. They probably entered the product key either by mistake or needed it for some of their testing. You can clear the key they used and use the one you purchased and I would recommend that.

Comment: Hi, Did yo checked with command line "slmgr /dlv", if the activation show as "licensed" and consistent with slmgr /xpr, it would be show as it is an used hardware device which have been activated. Even if we could reset or remove harddisk contents, but Microsoft activation server will record the activation information for hardware such as mother board, disk and other main party of PC.